# What is $\lim_{x \to \infty} 0^{\frac{1}{x}}$? Is it 0 or 1 or is it an invalid limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I’m unsure and lack the tools to find out if $\lim_{x \to \infty} 0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is 0 or 1 or is it an invalid limit. One way $0^0$ feels like it should give 1 but then again, the function is 0 for **all** $x$. So, how do we talk about such a limit? Also, does the limit remain the same when we replace $x$ by the natural number $n$. Please provide proper reasoning in your answers.

*Note:* Wolfram Alpha says that it is zero.

Comment: Since the base $0$ is constant, all values (for $0<x<\infty$) are $0$, so the limit is $0$.  This does not contradict the assertion that $0^0$ is indeterminate.  But for that you need a varying base as well as a varying exponent.

Comment: The case for irrational powers assumes that the base is positive. Thus $0^{1/x}$ is undefined for irrational $x$ and if we consider only the positive rational values of $x$ then it is identically equal to $0$ so that the desired limit is $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function is identically zero in $(0,\infty)$. For **any** positive $x$ we have $0^{\frac{1}{x}}=0$. So of course the limit in that case is zero, you can even easily prove this by the definition of the limit.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x\in\Bbb R^+$, we have $0^{1/x}=0$. This means $\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{1/x}=0$. Now, one thing to point out about this is that the base of the exponential is literally $0$ (not just something that approaches $0$). If you were to ask something like

> Given $f(x)\to0^+$ as $x\to\infty$, is $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x))^{1/x}=0$?

The answer to *this* question depends on the nature of $f(x)$ (specifically, how quickly it converges to $0$).